# Проблема при замене строк через strtr и preg_replace

Tags: php

Очень простое выражение замены почему-то не работает в вордпрессе. Нужно всего лишь заменить кавычку после пробела: [ "] - на кавычку-ёлочку: [ «] (опустим вопрос, почему не годится собственная замена вордпрессовского редактора).
Не работает в виде:

```
strtr($comment_text, " \"", " «")
```

Не работает в виде:

```
preg_replace('/\s"/', ' «', $comment_text);
preg_replace('/\ "/', ' «', $comment_text);
preg_replace('/ "/', ' «', $comment_text);
```

При этом замена работает и в том, и в другом виде, если вместо кавычки заменяется другой символ. Использование вместо кавычки мнемоник не помогло.

Почему именно в вордпрессе это не срабатывает и как можно обойти эту странность? Второй вопрос важнее, но и первый тоже хотелось бы понять.
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: а вы вот прям выведите `print_r([$comment_text, replace...]);die;` откройте исходный код страницы и посмотрите, что там было до и стало после. того глядишь, там и не кавычка

Comment: Там точно кавычка. Более того, если преобразовывать кавычку без пробела перед ней, вот так:
 preg_replace('/(\")/', ' «', $comment_text);
- то замена работает. Добавляю пробел - перестаёт.

Comment: И странное дело: если замену делать прямо в шаблоне страницы, то преобразование работает. Но не работает, когда оно в functions.php.
Не понимаю, что мешает. Файл в uft-8, проверено только что.

Answer (score 0):

Попробую объяснить, но только что касается функции `strtr()`.
Всё дело в нескольких следующих вещах:

1. Функцию `strtr()` можно использовать в двух разных режимах: с использованием трёх аргументов (в этом случае при поиске и сравнении заменяемой и заменяющей строки будет происходить побайтное преобразование - один символ на другой); и с использованием двух аргументов (второй аргумент - массив, и в этом случае поиск и сравнение ведётся уже более длинными строками).
2. Также если длины заменяемой и заменяющей строки разные, то уже "лишние" символы в более длинной строке никак использоваться в поиске и замене не будут.

Зная информацию из пункта №1 и №2, мы видим, что строка `" \""` содержит три символа: пробел, слеш, кавычку, а строка `" «"` - пробел и "ёлочку". Длина строк разная. Сравнение побайтовое (символ с символом). Получается следующее: ищем пробел->находим->заменяем. Ищем слеш->не находим->не заменяем. Конец. Далее ничего не ищем, так как "лишний" символ уже используется.

А решением будет использование функции `strtr()` с двумя аргументами.

```
$replace = array(" \"" => " «");
$text = 'просто текст с кавычками "В кавычках"';
$text = strtr($text, $replace);
var_dump($text); //просто текст с кавычками «В кавычках" - то, что нужно
```

А по поводу не срабатывания замены в functions.php - всё должно работать. Может, делаете это в какой-то другой функции, которая не пытается нигде вызываться и срабатывать..?

Comment: Увы, на самом деле изначально это делается именно через массив, я только для краткости вырезала одну пару "исходник/замена". Вот такое:

   ` $trans = array(
...
" \"" => " «",
 "\" " => "» ",
 "\"." => "».",
 "\"," => "»,",
 "\":" => "»:",
 "\"<" => "»<",
 "\)" => "»)",
 "\"." => "»$",
...
  );

$comment_text = strtr($comment_text, $trans);</pre>

Так что нет, это не помогает.
По поводу "в какой-то другой функции" - тоже нет: в массиве $trans много элементов (в коде выше примеры), и все они срабатывают, только этот холостой.

UPD.Не пойму, как сделать код кодом.

Comment: @ЮлияПанина, лишь напишу, что взял ваш массив замены пар, свою строку из примера выше, всё это "поместил" в отдельную функцию в functions.php, вызвал функцию в шаблоне страницы - всё работает. Напрашивается мысль "а точно ли там есть кавычка, которую так сильно пытаются найти?", но говорят, что есть).  `Код` в машинописные апострофы попробуйте добавлять

Comment: Опачки... Вы сказали "апостроф", имея в виду форматирование комментария, но мне пришло в голову заменить им кавычки в моём коде, вот так: `' \"' => ' «'`. И что вы думаете - заработало! Хотя у всех остальных выражений остались кавычки: `"\" " => "» "`. Я ещё буду испытывать, но проблема, похоже, решилась. Отличие между этим случаем и остальными вижу только одно: было две кавычки подряд, одна преобразуемая, а вторая синтаксическая; словно бы это чем-то не нравилось обработчику.

Comment: Правда, это не объясняет, почему выражение не работало в preg_replace. Но я бы не стала пытаться использовать preg_replace, если бы оно сразу заработало в strtr. И проверять сейчас preg_replace уже сил нет.